# Зачем использовать миксины?

Tags: вёрстка, оптимизация, sass, less, организация

Зачем в препроцессорах использовать миксины(mixins)?

Если мы можем создать специальный класс.

Например есть такая html структура:

```css
.default {
  text-align: center;
  backgorund-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

По сути мы можем создать миксин и применить его к `wrapper` и к `child`.
А можем и класс `.default` задать и тому и тому блоку.

Тогда вопрос, зачем вообще существуют препроцессоры? Либо есть какие-то моменты когда лучше использовать одно, а когда другое? Либо браузер вообще одинаково будет воспринимать и тот и тот вариант(Т.е. ему все равно будут эти стили применены к элементу непосредственно или посредством другого класса)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в больших проектах миксины удобны, если код повторяется или имеет вложенные классы, в приведенном примере разницы небудет, но если структура сложнее - миксины можно выгодно использовать , вот пример из документации https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/miksini/ispolzovanie_miksina.html

а вообще препроцессоры ускоряют сильно создание css , если к ним привыкнуть и быстро писать, я с emmet стараюсь на sass перейти.

Comment: браузеру на выходе будет без разницы, ведь препроцессоры все равно код на выходе в чистый css преобразуют

Comment: это то понятно, что в чистый css, но не скажется ли это на производительности страницы, ведь если записать класс какой-то и применять его везде в html, то кода получится меньше, чем писать одни и те же правила для каждого отдельного класса.

Comment: По логике вещей в теории да, но на практике часто встречаются всякие сайты типа bootstrap , где больше 10 классов в элементе, и они имеют большую скорость загрузки и зелёную зону, а в крупных проектах используются уже фреймворки и стайлгайды типо BEM.